# Swift 5- Firebase- Group by date in header

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, sections

My Main goal is to take the Date from the Firebase Database and use is as a section header so that i may load all the events that have the same date under that header.

I would like it to appear in my table view like this:

September -header

-September 29,2020 -sub header

--event

--event

--event

-september 30, 2020 -sub header

--event

--event

--event

This is my main View Controller.

```
import UIKit
    import Foundation
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase

    class EventsTableViewController: UIViewController {
        var sectionNames: [String] = []
        var events: [String: [EventsInfo]] = [:]
        var datref: DatabaseReference!
        var eventView = [EventsInfo]()

        @IBOutlet weak var eventTableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            getEventsFromFirebaseDB()
        }
        
        
        deinit {
               datref.removeAllObservers()
           }
           
           private func eventsFetched(_ eventData: [EventsInfo])
           {
               for event in eventData
               {
                guard let eventNameFirstChar = event.date.first else { continue }
                
                   if var eventsForKey = events["\(eventNameFirstChar)"]
                   {
                       eventsForKey.append(event)
                       events["\(eventNameFirstChar)"] = eventsForKey
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       // no users are stored in dictionary for key userNameFirstChar
                       events["\(eventNameFirstChar)"] = [event]
                   }
               }
           
               // sort dictionary keys and set it in sectionNames
               sectionNames = events.map { $0.key }.sorted()
            
            print (sectionNames)
           }
           
        private func getEventsFromFirebaseDB() {
               datref = Database.database().reference().child("events")
                datref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
               
                       guard snapshot.childrenCount > 0 else { return }
               
                       var events: [EventsInfo] = []
                       for event in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                       {
                           let object = event.value as? [String: AnyObject]
               
                           let title = object?["title"]
                           let place = object?["place"]
                           let info = object?["info"]
                           let date = object?["date"]
                           let time = object?["time"]
               
                        let event = EventsInfo(title: title as! String, place: place as! String, info: info as! String, time: time as! String, date: date  as! String)
                           events.append(event)
                            }

                    self?.eventsFetched(events)
                    self?.eventTableView.reloadData()
                        })
            }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "showEvent"
            {
                if let indexPath = eventTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                {
                    let destinationController = segue.destination as! EventsInfoViewController
                    let char = sectionNames[indexPath.section]
                    let event = events[char]![indexPath.row]
                    destinationController.EventsData = event
                }
            }
        }

    }


    extension EventsTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
        
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            sectionNames.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
              sectionNames[section]
          }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            let char = sectionNames[section]
               return events[char]!.count
            }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
            let cell = eventTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventsCell") as! EventsTableViewCell
            let char = sectionNames[indexPath.section]
            let event = events[char]![indexPath.row]
            cell.eventTitleLabel.text = event.title
            return cell
        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEvent", sender: self)
    }
```

This is my EventsInfo File

```
import Foundation


class EventsInfo {
    
    var title: String
    var place: String
    var info: String
    var time: String
    var date: String
    
    
    init(title: String, place: String, info: String, time: String, date: String) {
        
        self.title = title
        self.place = place
        self.info = info
        self.time = time
        self.date = date

    }
}
```

[image: This is what i current have but am looking to load the date into the section header instead]

[image: This is my Firebase file that I have my Date in for the TableView.]

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. *Pull the String*? Which string are you referring to? Why are you doing this `event.date.first` and why is the first character of the date an 's'? Also, what does this have to do with Firebase - it sounds like a tableView question. Your question states 'by date' but you've not told us how your sections are organized. Can you clarify?

Comment: @jay Sorry. I have updated the post with my data from Firebase. I may be approaching this all wrong but my intention is to display the date that is shown in the Database as a header and then list all objects of the same date under that header. The S is because is because it is pulling the first letter of September instead of the whole September name.  I used the similar dictionary style that i had for A contacts page that sorted all the users of that character together in a tableview.

Comment: That's better but still vague. Please include firebase structures as TEXT in the question, not an image. That way if we want to use it in an answer, we don't have to retype it. We don't know what `EventsInfo` looks like. It's also unclear what you're doing in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection` as `sectionNames[section]` doesn't mean anything - you should be returning what you want the section header to be. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay I have added more details. Hopefully this can help clarify what i am trying to convey

Comment: I understand what you want to do but that's not what your code is doing. It appears `events` is a dictionary whose key is the first letter of the event name. Then `sectionNames` is an array of those keys (the first letters). So the tableView sections are those letters. None of that has anything to do with your question - grouping by date. Try re-working the code code to utilize the dates as the section headers. You should model your objects (stored in the array) with a sectionTitle property and then an array to store the data that's held in each section.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. So my last question is what would be the best way to change the function so that instead of looking at the first letter and applying that to my array, that is would get the string instead? If that’s possible?  Thanks!

Comment: You just got too many things in the posted code to fix so I added an answer that may provide a better and more clear direction.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much! I’ll apply this to mine!

Comment: @Jay Sorry, I have one extra question. The confusion for me was that where you have the Fruit array and they are hard coded, thats where i want to put my data from Firebase. What would i need to have their to make sure it is getting the Firebase data and not code from here? I think that was my actual question but wasnt sure how to explain it.

Comment: That sounds like you're asking *how to I read data from firebase*? That's covered in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Read & Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write). If that's not what you're asking, can you clarify what you are asking? I would also suggest using my data or something similar as a template to get it working. Once that works and you have whatever data you want from Firebase it will be an easier transition.

Comment: Right,I understand your code. And I find it very useful, so thank you. My confusion was coming from where you are using the fruitArray  and having them hard coded in there and then loading them in. I am wanting that array to be obtained from my data in Firebase to apply to the rest of the code as you had yours.

Comment: I get it. It still sounds like you're asking how to read data from Firebase and populate an array. No? If you need assistance with that, we would be glad to help. Post a separate question with your existing Firebase code, a sample of your Firebase structure (as text) and then an explanation of the difficulty you're experiencing. Then we can definitely take a look and get you on the right track!

Comment: Yes, I will do that! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am tossing out an answer in hopes it will provide some direction though an example. Note that none of this is related to Firebase - it's purely tableView management.

Our app is a list is fruits with section titles being the first name of each fruit

```
A
   Apple
B
   Banana
```

etc

Here's a struct to hold each section's data and then a class array to hold those objects (the tableView dataSource)

```
struct FruitStruct {
   var sectionTitle = ""
   var fruitNameArray = [String]()
}

var fruitDataSource = [FruitStruct]()
```

then let's populate that data

```
func setupDataSourceData() {
    let fruitArray = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Bing Cherry", "Grape", "Orange", "Plum", "Watermelon", "Cantelope"]

    let allFirstChars = fruitArray.map { String($0.prefix(1)) } //get all first chars for section titles
    let sectionTitles = Array(Set(allFirstChars)).sorted() //eliminate dups and sort

    //iterate over the unique section titles and get the fruits that are in that section
    // sort and then craft structs to hold the title and the associated fruits
    sectionTitles.forEach { firstChar in
        let results = fruitArray.filter { $0.prefix(1) == firstChar }
        let sortedFruits = results.sorted()
        let fruit = FruitStruct(sectionTitle: firstChar, fruitNameArray: sortedFruits)
        fruitDataSource.append(fruit)
    }

    //this code is to just output the data to console so you can see what it
    //  looks like. Remove it.
    for fruitData in fruitDataSource {
        print(fruitData.sectionTitle)
        let fruits = fruitData.fruitNameArray
        for fruitName in fruits {
            print("  \(fruitName)")
        }
    }
}
```

lastly, the tableView delegate methods to populate the tableView from the dataSource

```
//
//handle sections
//
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.fruitDataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let title = self.fruitDataSource[section].sectionTitle
    return title
}

//
//handleTableView rows
//
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let rowsInSection = self.fruitDataSource[section].fruitNameArray.count
    return rowsInSection
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    let text = self.fruitDataSource[indexPath.section].fruitNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    return cell
}
```